# execute function after click OK (QDialogButtonBox)

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am using python 2.7 with PyQT5, this is my button:

```
self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 240, 341, 32))
self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
```

etc....

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(window)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how can I execute a function after click OK??

Comment: `window.accepted.connect(some_function)`.

Comment: thanks but it seems that: self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.function(inParameter)) do not like parameter in input....i have to use a function without in parameter......by the way now also the button "cancel" run my function....any solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't connect to `buttonBox.clicked`, because that will be called for *every* button.

Your button-box connections should look like this:

```
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
    self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
```

To run a function/slot when the dialog is accepted (i.e. only when the OK button is clicked), do this:

```
    self.accepted.connect(some_function)
```

If you want to pass a parameter, use a `lambda`:

```
    self.accepted.connect(lambda: some_function(param))
```

Comment: Thanks....in order to give a pratical solution the code below is fine: self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.close)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(lambda: self.run_command("tail -f /var/log/syslog"))    this will call a "tail" command if click "OK" and close the dialog if click "cancel"

Comment: Maybe things have changed since this answer was written, but I don't get "self.accepted.connect(some_function)" as a working solution.

Comment: @KarstenChu. Nothing has changed. It still works fine for me in both pyqt4 and pyqt5. I'm guessing you have failed to realise that `self.accepted` is a *separate signal* emitted by the dialog (rather than by the button-box). So when the okay button is clicked, it calls the dialog's `accept` slot, which in turn fires the dialog's `accepted` signal, which then calls `some_function`.

Answer (score 6):

You buttonBox setup should look like

```
self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
```

where `self.accept`is a function defined into the class.

```
def accept(self):
```

If you need to pass some parameters to the function you need to store these parameters into some class variables instead passing them as params into the function.